# Jersey/JAX-RS: Simultaneously stream input and output

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

How can I start returning a response to the Client before the request gets fully streamed to the Server with Jersey?
I would like to avoid buffering anything in the Server.

I have tried something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
public StreamingOutput post(InputStream inputstream) {
    MyCustomIterator<MyObject> it = new MyCustomIterator<>(inputsream);

    return output -> {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            MyObject obj = it.next();  // this read the object from the inputstream
            output.write(someConversion(obj));
        }
        output.flush;
    }
}
```

but it timeouts when the InputStream is huge:

```
ERROR o.g.j.s.ServerRuntime$Responder - An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity chunk to the container output stream.
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30003/30000 ms
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:234)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:141) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:242)
```

**EDIT**: I tried to replace the StreamingOutput by Jersey Async [ChunkedOutput](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#chunked-output) but I get the same timeout error.

Comment: You need to use a separate Thread for writing into your output and return the output immediately. The client gets noticed about the chunked response and should not close the connection until it has received the last element. Following the example by the link you have provided, will work out ;)